# Laravel pivot table that references more than two tables?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table

A little hard to explain but I'll try my best here:

```
Supplier
  id
  name
Product
  id
  name
Delivery_Method
  id
  name
Supplier_Product --pivot table
  id
  supplier_id
  product_id
  delivery_method_id
  delivery_time
```

Both my `Supplier` and `Product` tables are models however the delivery method isn't. I know how to use pivots to call stuff like `Product::with('suppliers')->get()` via this function in my `Product` model:

```
public function suppliers()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Supplier')->withPivot('delivery_time');
}
```

Whilst this works fine I'm still not getting the `delivery_method` as I don't know how to join `delivery_method_id` to get it's name. How can I achieve this?

Note that `delivery_method` does not have a model.

Comment: I kind of solved this after adding a `->join()` clause after my `withPivot()`. Solves my problem but I'm not sure if it's the "Laravel" way to do it. Still open to suggestions.

Comment: Why not create a Model for DeliveryMethod? You can also use query scope to define the ->join() if you are not using a model. So that your custom queries stay within the model file, which is easy to manage later. I would recommend you to use DeliveryMethod class as your model.